# Composer update package with OR operator to specific version

Tags: php, composer-php, version

Considering that Composer [supports](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#version-range) the `OR` operator and I have the following scenario:

**My project's composer.json**

```
require: {
    "vendor/dependencyA": "^1.0"
}
```

**Dependency A composer.json**

```
require: {
    "vendor/dependencyB": "^1.0 || ^2.0"
}
```

Considering that I don't have control over `Dependency A` composer.json file, how can I tell composer which version of `dependencyB` I prefer, if both meet the requirements?

Answer (score 1):

As stated by some fellows at the PHP chat, one way to achieve this is to add `dependencyB` to your project's composer.json:

**My project's composer.json**

```
require: {
    "vendor/dependencyA": "^1.0",
    "vendor/dependencyB": "^2.0"
}
```

This way you can specify the `dependencyB` version that is going to be used.